# HP Pavilion DV6 doesn't recognize wireless networks

Tags: hp-pavilion

Okay so about a few weeks after I got my laptop the wifi would connect and disconnect, off and on.

And every time I troubleshoot it, a message comes up saying there's a network cable not properly plugged in or broken...

It's been doing this for about a year and I usually just tap the bottom of the laptop or something and the wifi connects again but now it refuses to turn back on, how do I fix this?

Comment: I remember that some HP models had design issues (bad thermal design, if I'm not mistaken) that eventually led to this type of problem.

Comment: Yes the old dv6000 series had this issue among many others...Which OS? Which specific model of dv6....http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/findModel?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en

Answer (score 1):

Remove the screws on the back of the laptop that hold the cover over the Wifi adapter. Carefully detach the antenna connectors from the Wifi card remembering which goes where. Remove the Wifi card. Reseat it. Reconnect the antenna connectors, being very careful to push them straight on. Do not apply force until they're properly aligned.

Comment: Nope i just tried it and it didnt work. It just said "There may be a network cable unplugged or broken."

Answer (score 0):

[If it is the dv6000 series of laptop](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/findModel?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en), open Device Manager, does the wireless network adapter show up in there?

If it does not show in Device Manager, then you have a [motherboard problem which was very common](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=260674058980) on this series of laptop, there was a class action lawsuit against various manufacturers and nvidia, which has ended some years ago. If it does show in DM it could still be a motherboard issue.